# How do I use Jasmine to test a Phaser 3 project?

Tags: jasmine, phaser-framework

I am currently developing a minigame in the phaser.js framework, and since the scope of the project is quite large, I really want to work with unit tests.
However when trying to setup unit tests in Jasmine for Phaser, I run into errors regarding dependencies.

I am not experienced with Jasmine or any other testing framework, so it could be I am overlooking something obvious to a experienced developer.

My .spec file looks like this:

```
describe("motorMain", function() {
    var Phaser = require('../phaser');
    var MotorMain = require("../motorMain"); 

    var motorMain;
    var phaser;

    beforeEach(function() {
        phaser = new Phaser();
        motorMain = new motorMain();
      });

    it("should increase the score if a object is clicked", function(){
        var scoreBeforeClicking = motorMain.score;
        var gameobject;
        motorMain.clickhandler("",gameobject);
        expect(scoreBeforeClicking+1).toEqual(score);
    })
});
```

But since Phaser is reliant on running in a browser, when I run this it complains about not being able to access elements such as `window` and `document` in Phaser.

I get errors such as:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

Does anyone have experience with testing Phaser games? I can't seem to find any information on it online. Is it even possible to test phaser games?

As for other testing frameworks, I also looked into nightwatch, but it's Phaser support is outdated, and it is mainly e2e instead of unit-testing, so it isn't what I am looking for. I also saw online that there was a shimming version of Phaser 2.4.7 developed by someone, but this is outdated now that so much has changed in Phaser 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42909207/11912 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19320422/11912

Comment: I found recently that Phaser.Game can be created with a Phaser.HEADLESS type, that has "...This mode is meant for unit testing..." in the description.
I put this comment here, before trying to answer properly.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've got something working!

This is the bare minimum, but Phaser can be instantiated without errors.

***package.json***

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine --config=jasmine.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.6.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phaser": "^3.55.2"
  }
}
```

***jasmine.json***

```json
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ]
}
```

***spec/Phaser.Spec.js***

```js
require('canvas');
require('jsdom-global')();
const Phaser = require("phaser");

describe("A suite", function () {

    it("Instantiate a Phaser.Game", function () {
        let game = new Phaser.Game({ type: Phaser.HEADLESS });

        expect(game).not.toBe(null);
    })

})
```

The output in console is:

```
$ jasmine --config=jasmine.json
Randomized with seed 06585
Started
     Phaser v3.55.2-FB (Headless | HTML5 Audio)  https://phaser.io
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.016 seconds
Randomized with seed 06585 (jasmine --random=true --seed=06585)
✨  Done in 1.28s.
```